# Is typecasting a char* to int* undefined?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function to print the contents of a character array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(char * array, int n) {
    char* start;

    for(start = array; start - array < n && printf("%d\n", *start); start++);
}

int main() {
    char array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
    print_array(array, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

This works nicely printing:

```
97
98
99
100
101
```

The trouble begins if I change the function to this:

```
void print_array(int * array, int n) {
    int* start;

    for(start = array; start - array < n && printf("%d\n", *start); start++);
}
```

And then call the function like this:

```
print_array((int*)array, 5);
```

This prints junk.

```
1684234849
101
1973473280
8388443
80884992
```

I've turned on `-Wall` when compiling and it throws no warnings. Why exactly am I getting junk when I typecast the pointer?

Comment: Yes it is undefined. Other questions? Notice that you're also printing outside of the bounds, and all other stuff like that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes. Why didn't -Wall throw a warning?

Comment: This is C. It is the language designed to let shoot yourself in the foot. Here you're deliberately pointing the gun at your foot and pulling the trigger, so the compiler assumes you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude um wat? chars are promoted to ints in default argument promotions so not a single problem there, except due to possible sign extension... hardly undefined behaviour though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Blatantly false. Chars are promoted to ints or unsigned ints, there is no mismatch. Even the standard explicitly mentions this in printf documentation.

Comment: Is this a bad question?

Comment: `char *` is a pointer, **not** an array.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ "*Why didn't -Wall throw a warning?*" -- because with a **cast**, you're telling the compiler "don't bother me, I know what I'm doing here".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I don't think so. It's well-written with a good supporting code snippet. An obvious question is not necessarily a bad question since obviousness is subjective. Most C things are obvious to Olaf, for example

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [7.1.4: ... or a type **(after promotion)** not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined...](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4)

Comment: It could be UB exactly only when the `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` and `char` is not signed.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Okay I see it now. I'll admit defeat. I still think it's better to use the explicit `hh` prefix anyway. :)

Comment: No argument there; it exists for a reason.

Comment: Would appreciate a comment from the down voter.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Rather than `printf("%d\n"...`, use `printf("%x\n"...`.  I am confident the results will be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your second implementation is *undefined*.

And as others have stated, since you cast the address of *array* from (char *) to (int *), the compiler assumes you know what you are doing and doesn't throw a warning.  Try compiling without the cast to see your warning.

Now, to give you an architecture specific example of what is going on (NOTE this example is still *undefined*), consider this:

Assuming that the machine architecture uses 1 byte for char and 4 bytes for int ...

In your code:

```
char array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
```

You allocated an array of 5 char's.  They may look like this in memory:

```
0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x65
```

Then you call

```
print_array(array, 5);
```

In this usage and context, *array* is really an implicit pointer to *&array[0]*, which is (char *) and points to 0x61.

Now in the function call, you cast *array* to an (int *).  What you have is an array of 5 elements, each 1 byte wide, which is now being interpreted (NOTE: not converted) as an array of (still) 5 elements, each ... 4 bytes wide!  This may look like this in memory:

```
0x61626364 0x65?????? 0x???????? 0x???????? 0x????????
```

You only have 5 bytes defined of the needed 20 bytes in your (int *) implementation.

Depending on the endianness of your machine your first int could be interpreted as

- 1684234849 (little endian - see your result above)
- 1633837924 (big endian)

You already noted that the other 4 elements when printed are garbage, since we don't know the contents of memory.

Note also that you over-flowed your char[5] array on the second "int" element.

Again, this example is architecture dependent and *undefined*.  You could have completely different behavior on another architecture.

Edit:
It looks like by chance, your second "int" is

```
0x65000000
```

And in little endian interpretation: 101 just like you see in your output.

But this is luck.  It could be any garbage.

Answer (score 6):

Conversion from an `int*` to a `const char*` is well-defined.

The converse is also true if the the underlying data is an `int[]` array, but you cannot convert arbitrary points in an array pointed to by a `const char*` pointer to an `int*`: you might not be respecting alignment requirements.

In your case therefore the behaviour is *undefined*, since you started off with a `char` array.

Comment: Is the conversion from `int *` to `char *` well-defined as well? Is there any specific reason why you point out the `const char*` typecast?

Comment: @SebNag: Absolutely! It **must** be a `const char*`.

Comment: not respecting alignment requirements is just one thing, breaking strict aliasing is 2nd, and 3rd (mostly hypothetical on normal computers nowadays) would be trap values in `int`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Let me explain myself. I apologise for unmarking your answer. However, please look at the answer I did mark. I believe it explained the reason for my output very clearly.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: That's no problem. I tend to shy away from attempting to explain undefined behaviour as it can often be rather futile. Really the best recourse is to inspect the generated assembly. That said though, my brief answer only really scratches the surface.